# fetch image and convert it to data-uri format

Tags: php, curl, data-uri

I am interested in requesting an image through HTTP with PHP, then converting the image to a data URI. How would I go about doing this?

For example:

```
$img = file_get_contents("http://something.com/something.png");

$datauri = magicalfunction($img);

echo("<img src=\"$datauri\" />");
```

I know I used `file_get_contents()` there, but I would prefer a solution that doesn't use the file functions. If possible, I'd like to use cURL.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data URI is composed by the literal `data:`, then the media type (defaults to text-plain if omitted), `;base64` if you are encoding (which you should, if you have binary data as an image), and then the data itself.

[Linky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) to some docs.

You could do it like this:

```
// Your image
$image = 'crazy_cat.jpg';

$myvar = file_get_contents($image);

function srcData($image)
{

    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);

    // reads your image's data and convert it to base64
    $data = base64_encode($image);

    // Create the image's SRC:  "data:{mime};base64,{data};"
    return 'data: ' . finfo_buffer($finfo, $image) . ';base64,' . $data;

}

echo "<img src='" . srcData($myvar) . "'/>";
```

Ta da!

If you are downloading the image before serving it like `data`, you'd have to do it before calling this function, and pass the function the buffer containing the file.

For bonus points: the "how to use curl" can be summarized thus:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/408/287.jpg');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$myvar = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
```

And you'll have your image in `$myvar`, ready to pass to `srcData()`.

Comment: What would be a cURL implementation of this? Generally it's considered insecure to use `file_get_contents()`, and while I can easily replace that myself, I'm not sure about the `finfo_` functions.

Comment: this is meant to be used in your local file system. downloading of the image is a separate matter and shouldn't be handled by the same function. just download it in whichever way you want, and pass it to the function.

Comment: there, now I edited to properly separate its responsibilities. now it's clearer that the downloading, via curl, file_get_contents, or whichever way you use, should happen **BEFORE** using this. If you have trouble using curl, it's a different question (and one that's asked very often around here, search and you'll find many recipes for that)